# Finding canonical ordering of a planar graph

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, planar-graphs

is the canonical ordering of a planar graph unique? Can there be just one ordering or different ordering depending on the choice of vertex selection? Is there any such fixed rule to do choose a vertex from the outer circle of a graph or anyone from the outer circle can be chosen for ordering at a time?

[image]

In the above image can the number 14 and 15 be interchanged?

Comment: Are we talking about a graph that has a planar embedding, a planar graph embedded in a particular way, or a planar straight-line graph?

Comment: Then there's no distinguished outer circle.

Comment: (For the specific example, no; 15 has a neighbor of degree 7 (vertex 10), whereas 14 has no such neighbor.)

Comment: Are you asking if the labelling choice of the outer face uniquely determines the ordering of the other vertices? There are certainly algorithms for canonical labelling of planar graphs (eg. Kukluk, Holder, and Cook (2004)) if that's what you want?

Comment: what if no 14 had also a neighbor of degree 7 like no 15? @David Eisenstat

Comment: No - it is not unique. The canonical ordering of 14 and 15 can be swapped as can the canonical ordering of vertices 4-12 (provided 4 < 5 < 6 < 11 < 12 and 7 < 8 < 9 < 10) - so you could have it ordered 1,2,3,7,4,5,8,9,6,11,12,10,13,15,14,16.